# Reset jQuery AJAX timeout externally

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I was wondering if there is any possibility through which one can reset the timeout of an AJAX request through an 'external' control. For example, let's say I have the following:

```
jQuery.fn.worker = function worker() {
    $.get('/home/GetData', function (data) {
        // Manipulate retrieved data
    });
    setTimeout(worker, 30000);
};
```

Would it be possible to have, let's say, a button through which I could reset the worker's timeout?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you make the timer available globally, you can use `clearTimeout(timer)`.

```
var timer = setTimeout(worker, 30000); // create
clearTimeout(timer);  // clear
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the scope.  I was doing `var t = setTimeout(...);` inside a function and it wasn't clearing. Then after reading your answer, I tried `var t;` outside the function and it reset the timeout as expected.